# PHP delete function in a forum

Tags: php, mysql

I have created this php file to allow users to delete posts on my forum. What i am trying to do is make sure users will be able to delete only their own posts UNLESS they are an administrator. So far users are able to delete their own posts. However Administrators cannot delete posts that they did not create and the code returns false at the DELETE query. What am i doing wrong?

user_level at 2 or higher is an administrator. 0 is for normal user.

Note: i am aware of the SQL injection vulnerabilities in this code. I will fix it once the logical part is complete.

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
include 'header.php';

$id = $_GET['post_id'];

if (isset($_SESSION['signed_in'])) {

    $sql= "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id=$id";
    $post_data=$link->query($sql);
    if($post_data->num_rows > 0) {
        if($row=$post_data->fetch_assoc()) {
        }
    }
    if (!$_SESSION['user_level'] === 2  ) {

        echo 'You need to be an admin to delete other peoples posts.';
    }
    else {

        if ($_SESSION['user_id'] === $row['post_by']) {
            $delsql2= 'DELETE FROM posts WHERE post_id='.$id;
            $stmt2= $link->query($delsql2);
            header ('Location:index.php');
        }
        else {
            var_dump($_SESSION);
            echo 'You can only delete your own posts.';
        }
    }
}
else {
    echo 'You must be signed in to delete a post.';
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried checking to see what the value of "$_SESSION['user_level']" is? What does that equal?

Comment: The user_level is 2 for this user.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Therefore all of your "only allow mods to delete anyone's stuff" checking is pointless. it can be trivially bypassed by injecting the sql.

Comment: Yes but when you are admin and you says it doesn't work. What does "$_SESSION['user_level']" return when it doesn't work?

Comment: Remove the exclamation point before `$_SESSION['user_level']` and replace `===` with `!==`

Comment: #Marc B - Like i said, Security will be adjusted once i fix the initial problem.

Comment: #Charlie Fish - It returns "2" like i said.

Comment: #Charlotte Dunois - No luck with that operator either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to see if the person is admin OR if it's their own post, then do that in one if:

```
    if (($_SESSION['user_id'] === $row['post_by']) || $_SESSION['user_level'] === 2 ) {
        $delsql2= 'DELETE FROM posts WHERE post_id='.$id;
        $stmt2= $link->query($delsql2);
        header ('Location:index.php');
    }
    else {
        var_dump($_SESSION);
        echo 'You can only delete your own posts.';
    }
```

This will eliminate the first (bad) if statement.

Comment: I was sure this would work... It still returns false.

Comment: How does it return false? Which echo does it output?

Comment: "You can only delete your own posts." While being logged into a user with user_level of 2.

Comment: You may need to try double-checking each statement within your else, to see where it's failing: `echo "({$_SESSION['user_id']} === {$row['post_by']}) = ".($_SESSION['user_id'] === $row['post_by']); echo "{$_SESSION['user_level']} === 2? ". ($_SESSION['user_level'] === 2);`

Comment: Another thing you might want to try is to reduce your validation from `===` to `==`. user_level might actually be a string 2, which won't match an integer 2.

Comment: It returns with (1 === 2) = 2 === 2. So it clearly shows that this post doesn't belong to the user. But, the user_ level is definetly a 2 which should give it the permission?

Comment: You fixed it my friend :) it was the validation, after changing it from === to == it worked. Thank you very much ! :D

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison is flawed

```
if (!$_SESSION['user_level'] === 2) {
```

This does not mean "if level is not 2", it means "if not level is two". You need to put the inequality in the right place

```
if ($_SESSION['user_level'] !== 2) {
```

Or if for some reason you really want to logically negate then

```
if (!($_SESSION['user_level'] === 2)) {
```

Comment: I have tried it before and it didn't fix the issue. and apologies for the flaw i am very new to programming.